# Sort tags by post count

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-interface, profile-page

Currently the only options for sorting tags in the profile page is by `votes` or `name`. Can we include the option to sort by post count? I think this will be useful because it more accurately reflects a user's interests than sorting by `votes`. It would look pretty much like this:

[image: UI Mockup]

In the following example `sql-server` would come after `.net`, followed by `asp.net-mvc`.

[image: Tags by votes]

Comment: You could use this [Data.Se query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/104591/users-tags-by-post-count)

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter Thanks that works, but it doesn't count question tags. Also, my main point was to see if we can get support for that directly on the profile page.

Comment: It counts either answers or questions. That's why the weird join clause of `pt.PostID = p.id or pt.postID = q.id`

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter hmm well then the numbers I'm getting are very inconsistent with my profile page.

Comment: Looks like something's wrong, I'm looking into it

Comment: I found the problem. Data.Se was refreshed on Mar 17 and you've been [fairly active since then](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1715579+%5Bc%23%5D+created%3A2013-03-17..2013-03-22)

Answer (score 2):

This was a feature I wanted as well, so I created a query on data.SE to do it:

[My Tags by Post Count](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/356006/my-tags-by-post-count)

Hope it helps for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how they sorted the [list](/questions/tagged/list) and [casting](/questions/tagged/casting), but in [my profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1190388/dream-eater?tab=tags), the sorting seems to be done like this:

1. Tag with most votes at top([php](/questions/tagged/php)).
2. Tags with equal scores but different number of answers I have are sorted based on number of answers(`DESC` order).
3. Use alphabetical sorting at the end to sort remaining tags with same score and same number of answers.

[image]

Comment: Right, I'd basically like it to sort by (2), then (1), then (3).